# How to convert a VARCHAR to a date in ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have that field in my table:

```
2020-01-16T10:55:16..296518000
```

How to convert this Varchar into a date in format 'YYYY-MM-DD' ?

I tried:

```
select TRUNC(to_date(DATE_UPDATED ,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'))  from JOB_SCHEDULE_TBL
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `substr()`:

```
select to_date(SUBSTR(DATE_UPDATED, 1, 10) ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

The `trunc()` is unnecessary.

Comment: could you write me please how to convert to another date format? I tried select to_date(SUBSTR(DATE_UPDATED, 1, 18) ,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from JOB_SCHEDULE_TBL but it doesnt work :(

Comment: @AnnaK Do the substr() by itself to see what it pulls out. It needs to match your format string. Try this: `select to_date(SUBSTR(DATE_UPDATED, 1, 10) || ' ' || substr(DATE_UPDATED, 12,8) ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from JOB_SCHEDULE_TBL;`

Comment: Thanks kfinity but an output is still 01/16/2020

Comment: @AnnaK If you want a date to display in a specific text format, you need `TO_CHAR()`. E.g. `to_char(to_date(SUBSTR(DATE_UPDATED, 1, 10),'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Comment: @AnnaK . . . What the date looks like depends on the date setting on your instance of Oracle.  You can convert to a string -- as kfinity suggests -- if you want a particular format.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the format of `DATE` with what you are seeing on the screen. A `DATE` data type has no "format". It's Oracle's internal, binary format. Even when you `SELECT TO_DATE` ..., the result is going to get displayed by the client, and to do so the client will have to peform (under the covers) a `TO_CHAR` on the resulting `DATE`. And that implied to_char will use the current system/session/ settings for `TNS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: Of course it is possible. You simply have to apply a final to_char to display it the way you want:  select to_char(to_date(SUBSTR(DATE_UPDATED, 1, 10) ,'YYYY-MM-DD'),yyyy-mm-dd) from job_schedule_tbl.    Read more about handling date 'formats' here:  https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Comment: but how about formating it in this way: YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss???

Comment: You can format your final to_char any way you want.  Everything inside of that is dependent on the format of your original character data.  And on review, are you sure that your DATE_UPDATED column is a varchar and not some variant of a TIMESTAMP?  If it really is a varchar, then that is a sever design flaw.  Dates and times should _always_ be stored in either DATE or some variant of TIMESTAMP., not character strings (some variant of varchar).

Comment: Thanks. That was a good hint. I fixed my problem. Thank you :)